# Cant get 'apps' to show in AVD

Tags: android, cordova, android-virtual-device

EDIT:
Seems i was on the right track all along, 10+ (or so) restarts and voila. It works.

As a first, i'm trying to get the AVD up and running, and test it with a real simple 'helloWorld'.

I'm using Android 4.0.3, if that might matter.

After having loads of trouble with memory allocation, and run-times and you name it..
The AVD is now up and running, without warnings or errors.

And i can install my project on it..

```
[2012-04-17 23:28:04 - AndroidProj] Android Launch!
[2012-04-17 23:28:04 - AndroidProj] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-17 23:28:04 - AndroidProj] Performing com.phonegap.helloworld.AndroidProjActivity activity launch
[2012-04-17 23:28:09 - AndroidProj] Uploading AndroidProj.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-04-17 23:28:12 - AndroidProj] Installing AndroidProj.apk...
[2012-04-17 23:28:54 - AndroidProj] Success!
[2012-04-17 23:28:54 - AndroidProj] Starting activity com.phonegap.helloworld.AndroidProjActivity on device emulator-5554
```

All the code i'm using is pretty much just copy+paste from tutorial(s):

The 'main' java-file. (@ AndroidProj/src/com.phonegap.helloworld)

```
package com.phonegap.helloworld;

import org.apache.cordova.*;
/*import com.phonegap.DroidGap;*/
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AndroidProjActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

And the html (@ AndroidProj/assets/www)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.phonegap.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
    />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidProjActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
        <intent-filter> </intent-filter> 
        </activity> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Besides the fact that i takes forever and ever to install my project, it seems to be carried out correctly.
But, all i get is the emulator, my project/file is nowhere to be found.
Any clues to where the problem might lie?

[image]

Comment: Paste your manifest.xml also....

Comment: Please select the green check mark left to the answer which solved the problem instead of writing it to the title. If no given answer was right and you solved it on your own, just write an answer yourself and select it as the right one (instead of editing your question). +1 for nicely formatted question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice, i'll 'answer' this myself.

Turns out there was no problem, at least not code-wise, a bunch of restarts later and it all runs smoothly.

Thanks for your efforts, though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running it directly from installed applications? 
as the install was successful, you should be a

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I restarted eclipsed and all is well.

Answer (score -1):

Use the mouse Luke - click on the 3rd icon on the bottom the circle with the rectangles 
this will show all your apps the little green man will display with helloworld